# Why some shortcuts aren't listed on index.txt ? Is there a complete list?

Tags: key-bindings, help-system

The file [index.txt](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/runtime/doc/index.txt) is claiming to be a list of all commands,
but some keyboard shortcuts are listed on other files and not here.
And sometimes, the definition is a bit different in other files.
Are they errors, or is there a reason like backward compatibility?
If someone knows a more complete shortcuts list, it can also help me.

#### The main missing / different shortcuts I found are :

- The shortcuts `[M` and `]M` with a capital `M` are listed in [motion.txt](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/runtime/doc/motion.txt) but are not in `indext.txt`.
  `index.txt` contains only those with small `m`.
- The shortcut `]m` has a different meaning: "cursor N times forward to end of member
  function" in `index.txt`,
  and "Go to [count] next start of a method…" in `motion.txt`.
- The shortcuts `[S` and `]S` with a capital `S` are listed in [spell.txt](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/runtime/doc/spell.txt) but are not in `index.txt`.
- `zg` and `zG` has the same definition in `index.txt` but different definitions in `spell.txt`.
  `zb` and `zB` has the same problem.
- `v_CTRL-A` and `v_g_CTRL-A` has the same definition in `index.txt` but different in [change.txt](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/runtime/doc/change.txt).

Comment: It seems unlikely to be an oversight given that there's a general theme: don't show the upper-case versions in the index. That being said it doesn't seem very user-friendly. You could report it. BTW, in my index.txt I have `zg` and `zug` the latter of which says "undo zg" plus `zG` and `zuG` ("undo zG"). And I don't see `v_CTRL-A` or `v_g_CTRL-A` as having different definitions...the index.txt text is just abbreviated (perhaps not ideally, though). One shouldn't use the index as the authoritative documentation..it's a cheat sheet basically (with tag links to the main docs).

Comment: For `zug` and `zuG`, I will assume it's my mistake as long as they currently are in official repo in `index.txt`.  But `v_CTRL-A` and `v_g_CTRL-A` also are, respectively on line `904` and `970` : the first command adds `1` to every line, the second adds `1` to first line, `2` to second line, `3` to third line and so on. If the index isn't the authoritative documentation, is there one? or is there any more complete list?

Comment: `v_CTRL-A` and `v_g_CTRL-A` both increment a single number by N (aka `{count}`). The index is accurate in that respect. The functionality you're referring to is for selection of multiple numbers. Due to its abbreviated form, the index, wisely or not, doesn't include that variation. Regarding authoritative documentation, as is usually the case there is just one and that's the primary help entries. IOW, there's no authoritative index. If there's an unofficial but arguably better index out there I've not seen it myself.